# Laravel nested controller with restful

Tags: laravel, php

In my Laravel Project, I have following folder structures

`application/controllers/products.php`

`application/controllers/products/categories.php`

In my `products.php`

```
class Products_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;    

    public function get_index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Products List';
        return View::make('product.index',$data);
    }    
}
```

in my `categories.php`

```
class Products_Categories_Controller extends Base_Controller{

    public $restful = true;    

    public function get_index(){

        $data['title'] = "All Categtories";

        return View::make('category.index', $data);
    }    
}
```

this is my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('products', array('as' => 'products', 'uses' => 'products@index'));
Route::get('products/categories', array('as' => 'categories', 'uses' => 'categories@index'));
```

When I browse the `example.com/products/categories`, I've got 404 error message. Whats wrong with my `routes.php`

Comment: Do you have proper rewrite rules set for your server?

Comment: yeah.. site is working perfectly.. but I can't go to categories page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```php
Route::get('products/categories', array('as' => 'categories', 'uses' => 'products.categories@index'));
```

Note the `'uses' => 'products.categories@index'`